# Microsoft Graph API Error - The specified object was not found in the store., Default folder AllItems not found

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to read emails of user a user in a tenant. The admin has granted consent for the following permissions:

```
offline_access AccessReview.Read.All AccessReview.ReadWrite.All Channel.ReadBasic.All ChannelMessage.Read.All ChannelSettings.Read.All Chat.Read ChatMessage.Read DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Mail.Read Mail.Read.Shared Mail.ReadBasic Mail.ReadWrite MailboxSettings.Read openid profile TeamMember.Read.All TeamSettings.Read.All User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All email
```

However, both in graph explorer and in PHP code, when I query the endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_email>/messages`, I get the error:

```
"error": {
        "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
        "message": "The specified object was not found in the store., Default folder AllItems not found.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-11-29T09:16:49",
            "request-id": "2449c64a-9aa8-479d-8de4-923a2a306583",
            "client-request-id": "5eb26a2e-54da-bba2-0adf-4fa7bca43df2"
        }
    }
```

What could I be doing wrong?

[image: Here is a screenshot of AD permissions]

Comment: Does your application use delegated or application permissions?

Comment: @user2250152 on Azure AD, I have given both delegated and application.

Comment: @user2250152 I have edited the question and added a screenshot of the permissions.

Comment: Does your application run as a daemon or access the API as the signed-in user?

Comment: @user2250152 the tenant admin signs in with their Microsoft account (Outh2 flow) after which a token and refresh token is issued. From there on, the applications runs as daemon (but I think mimicking the admin user).